# Subquery returned more than 1 value with case

Tags: sql-server, etl

I write a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CASE co.grdtxtCertificationOther 
        WHEN 'อย.' THEN  2 
        WHEN 'มผช.' THEN 3 
        WHEN 'มอก.' THEN 4 
        WHEN 'ฮาลาล' THEN 5
        WHEN 'Q' THEN 6 
        WHEN 'GMP' THEN 7 
        WHEN 'GAP' THEN 8
        WHEN 'HACCP' THEN 9 
        WHEN 'เกษตรอินทรีย์' THEN 10 
        ELSE 1 
        END As ID, 
        co.[grdtxtCertificationOther] AS STDName,
        co.[grdtxtCertificationNumberOther] AS STDNumber,
        CONVERT( VARCHAR(24),
           ( SELECT CASE 
             WHEN LEN(grddatIssueDateOther) >4 THEN grddatIssueDateOther
             END  
             FROM custom.[tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther] 
             WHERE dp.id = co.[_parent]
           ),109
        ) AS SentDate,  
        dp.libtxtUserID AS ParentID,
        1 AS Displayorder,
        0 AS isDisable
        FROM Custom.tblR_docProduct dp
        INNER JOIN  [Custom].[tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther] co
        ON dp.Id = co._Parent
    ) t
```

and it shows the error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or 
when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

on this

```
(
 SELECT CASE 
 WHEN LEN(grddatIssueDateOther) >4 THEN grddatIssueDateOther
 END  
 FROM custom.[tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther] 
 WHERE dp.id = co.[_parent]),109
) As SentDate
```

I don't know why and got stuck on it

Comment: What is the result of running just the error query?

Comment: yes the result is just a error

Comment: Let me clarify. Try to run the query `SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(...)'. Does it return more than 1 row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you just want:

```
SELECT CASE co.grdtxtCertificationOther
            WHEN 'อย.' THEN  2
            WHEN 'มผช.' THEN 3
            WHEN 'มอก.' THEN 4
            WHEN 'ฮาลาล' THEN 5
            WHEN 'Q' THEN 6
            WHEN 'GMP' THEN 7
            WHEN 'GAP' THEN 8
            WHEN 'HACCP' THEN 9
            WHEN 'เกษตรอินทรีย์' THEN 10 ELSE 1 END As ID
        , co.[grdtxtCertificationOther] AS STDName
        , co.[grdtxtCertificationNumberOther] AS STDNumber
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),
           CASE 
              WHEN LEN(co.grddatIssueDateOther) >4 THEN co.grddatIssueDateOther
                   END,109) As SentDate  
        , dp.libtxtUserID  As ParentID
        , 1 AS Displayorder
        , 0 AS isDisable
                   FROM Custom.tblR_docProduct dp
INNER JOIN  [Custom].[tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther] co
ON dp.Id = co._Parent
```

Because at the moment, your subquery is an uncorrelated one - it introduces a *new* reference to the `tblR_docProduct_grdCertificationOther` table, but then the `WHERE` clause only makes assertions about the outer reference (with the alias `co`) and the `Custom.tblR_docProduct` table (with the alias `dp`).

If you really did want a subquery, it's difficult to tell what it should be since the `WHERE` clause inside your attempt seems to be identical to the current `JOIN` condition between `co` and `dp`.

It's also unclear why you had an outer query that just performed a `SELECT *` on a single subquery.

Comment: Thank you very much @Damien you are my man, there's can solved my problem and thanks for your new knowledge